# Why does hasattr execute the @property decorator code block

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties

In Python when I call the `hasattr` on a `@property` decorator the `hasattr` function actually runs the `@property` code block.

E.g. a class:

```
class GooglePlusUser(object):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

    def get_user_id(self):
        return self.master.google_plus_service.people().get(userId='me').execute()['id']


    @property
    def profile(self):
        # this runs with hasattr
        return self.master.google_plus_service.people().get(userId='me').execute()
```

Running the following code calls the profile property and actually makes the call:

```
#Check if the call is an attribute
if not hasattr(google_plus_user, call):
    self.response.out.write('Unknown call')
    return
```

Why? How can I solve this without making the api call?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`hasattr()` works by actually *retrieving the attribute*; if an exception is thrown `hasattr()` returns `False`. That's because that is the only reliable way of knowing if an attribute exists, since there are so many dynamic ways to inject attributes on Python objects (`__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`, `property` objects, meta classes, etc.).

From the [`hasattr()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

> This is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an exception or not.

If you don't want a property to be invoked when doing this, then don't use `hasattr`. Use `vars()` (which returns the instance dictionary) or `dir()` (which gives you a list of names on the class as well). This won't let you discover dynamic attributes handled by `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` hooks however.

Comment: Went with `dir` and that did the trick for me. Thanks again Martijn.

Comment: Important to note: if *any* Exception is thrown, it concludes that it has attr not.

Comment: @felix: only in Python 2, in Python 3 only `AttributeError` will cause `hasattr()` to return `False`. Other exceptions are propagated.

Comment: Better, though still any AttributeError raised anywhere within that method call will do it. I just fixed an issue where there are database calls happening because I mistakenly thought I could do object feature testing using `hasatttr`

Comment: @felix: Yes, any `AttributeError` will do that, because there is no way to distinguish between intentional and accidental attribute errors.

Comment: I use a try/except AttributeError block to avoid calling hasattr. in the try section is call getattr.

Answer (score 6):

`hasattr` is basically implemented like this (except in C):

```
def hasattr(obj, attrname):
    try:
        getattr(obj, attname)
    except AttributeError:
        return False
    return True
```

So in true "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (EAFP) fashion, to find out if an object has a given attribute, Python simply tries to get the attribute, and converts failure to a return value of `False`. Since it's really getting the attribute in the success case, `hasattr()` can trigger code for `property` and other descriptors.

To check for an attribute without triggering descriptors, you can write your own `hasattr` that traverses the object's method resolution order and checks to see whether the name is in each class's `__dict__` (or `__slots__`). Since this isn't attribute access, it won't trigger properties.

Conveniently, Python already has a way to walk the method resolution order and gather the names of attributes from an instance's classes: `dir()`. A simple way to write such a method, then, would be:

```
# gingerly test whether an attribute exists, avoiding triggering descriptor code
def gentle_hasattr(obj, name):
    return name in dir(obj) or hasattr(obj, name)
```

Note that we fall back to using `hasattr()` if we can't find the desired name in `dir()`, because `dir()` won't find dynamic attributes (i.e., where `__getattr__` is overridden). Code for these will still be triggered, of course, so if you don't care that you don't find them, you could omit the `or` clause.

On balance, this is wasteful, since it gets all relevant attribute names when we're interested only in whether a specific one exists, but it'll do in a pinch. I'm not even sure that doing the loop yourself rather than calling `dir()` would be faster on average, since it'll be in Python rather than in C.

Comment: Didn't believe this at first but it's true. If `attrname` specifies a property which raises `AttributeError` `hasattr` confusingly returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Making the variable as a class variable and then calling hasattr on it did the trick for me.

```
if not hasattr(google_plus_user, GooglePlusUser.call):
  self.response.out.write('Unknown call')
  return
```