# getattr(object, 'name', False) v.s. hasattr(object,'name')

Tags: python, django

I am learning to compose professional codes through exploring Django source code.

In [django.urls.resolvers | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/urls/resolvers/), it reads:

```
class LocaleRegexProvider(object):
    def describe(self):
        description = "'{}'".format(self.regex.pattern)
        if getattr(self, 'name', False):
            description += " [name='{}']".format(self.name)
        return description
```

I assume that `getattr(self, 'name', False):` can be substituted by more readable code `hasattr(self, 'name')`

For exmaple

```
In [22]: if getattr(str,'split',False):
    ...:     print("Str has 'split' attribute")
    ...: else:
    ...:     print("Str has not 'split' attribute")
    ...:
Str has 'split' attribute
In [25]: if getattr(str,'sp',False):
...:     print("Str has 'sp' attribute")
...: else:
...:     print("Str has not 'sp' attribute")
...:
Str has not 'sp' attribute
```

As for `hasattr`

```
In [23]: if hasattr(str,'split'):
    ...:     print("Str has 'split' attribute")
    ...: else:
    ...:     print("Str has not 'split' attribute")
    ...:
Str has 'split' attribute
In [24]: if hasattr(str,'sp'):
...:     print("Str has 'sp' attribute")
...: else:
...:     print("Str has not 'sp' attribute")
...:
Str has not 'sp' attribute
```

It seems `hasattr`short and readable.

There's a question about their comparison which do not cover this point. [Python hasattr vs getattr - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971061/python-hasattr-vs-getattr)

Is it a better practice to apply `getattr()` in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasattr` and `getattr` do different things and are not interchangeable in this case.

Consider the case where the `name` value is set to be an empty string. `hasattr(self, 'name')` will return `True`, while `getattr(self, 'name', False)` will return that empty string - which is evaluated as `False` in a boolean context.

To replace the `getattr` call, you'd need something like `if hasattr(self, 'name') and self.name:`, which does two attribute lookups rather than one.