# Unable to set sequential to false in a torchtext LABEL field

Tags: pytorch

I'm having trouble setting the sequential attribute for a field to False. My code includes the following.

```
LABEL = data.Field(sequential=False)
```

But when I check whether sequential is False or not...

```
hasattr(LABEL, 'sequential')
```

I get "True". When I try to set the attribute...

```
LABEL.sequential = False
hasattr(LABEL, 'sequential')
```

I still get True!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Good catch ! There are some texts talking about problems in `hasattr()` like:

1. [Python hasattr vs getattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971061/python-hasattr-vs-getattr)
2. [hasattr() – A Dangerous Misnomer](https://hynek.me/articles/hasattr/)

Instead, you can use `getattr()` and you will see the correct result.